# Node/Express with connect-redis, how handle session expiry

Tags: node.js, express, redis, node-redis, express-session

I have a **Node/Express** application that use **redis** as session store.

I have a question concerning the handling of the **expiry of the session**.

I'd like have an active session until the browser is closed, so I didn't set a session expiration time.

Doing that the session cookie works fine, but I have a doubt about Redis.

It seems that the couple Key/Value stored in Redis DB never expire.

How is the right way to handle this?

There is a way to configure redis to destroy a value stored with a certain idle time?

Or is better set a TTL when the connect-redis is invoked inside the application?

---

*Actual configuration of the session inside the application:*

```
var session = require('express-session');
var RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

app.use(session({
  store: new RedisStore({port:6379, host: 'localhost'}),
  secret: "my-secret-here",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Redis with express-session, you can use the touch() method from express-session to reset the TTL. So if you set a TTL when creating the session, do something like this on the routes where you don't want the session to expire:

```
api.get("/someRoute/", (req, res) => {
  req.session.touch();

  // Whatever else you need to do
  res.sendStatus(200);
}
```

That will reset the TTL on Redis and prevent the session from expiring assuming the client is still hitting your API - I'm assuming that if the client doesn't interact with your API for long enough, that implies the browser is closed or otherwise finished using your app.

Comment: The method touch() set the cookie.maxAge? But session cookie has not a maxAge setted. The cookie expire when the browser is closed.
Maybe could I set a TTL for the data stored into Redis DB and use something like a store.touch() to refresh the TTL.
This could be correct?

Comment: I tried to set a Redis TTL value, the command req.session.touch() that you suggested works fine. It refresh the Idletime of the key stored into Redis DB.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify a ttl while creating the session store.
You can find more options in the [readme](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-redis).

```
app.use(session({
    store: new RedisStore(options),
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    ttl : 20 // ttl is in seconds. From the readme.
}));
```

Comment: Yes I thing something like this. I really didn't know the right time to set in, but i'll try with different values.
How is possible to reset the TTL?
I must use req.session.touch() as suggested by Levi or something like store.touch()?
I didn't understand that.

Comment: You can use `touch` or just set a ttl and forget about it.